# Enter keypress not detected when JS app deployed, works fine locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, npm, chromium

I have a JS application that allows a user to add text boxes to a panel and enter text. They can either click away from the text box or hit enter on their keyboard to submit. Strangely when this is deployed (using NPM build) it doesn't seem to detect the enter button key press event. I added a console.log message to fire when the enter key is pressed but this only appears when I run locally.

Any ideas why this could happen?

See code below. This works fine locally but doesn't seem to fire when deployed on our AWS instance.

```
onReturnKeyPressed: function() {
        if (!textHandler.text || !textHandler.text.length) return;
        this.appendPoints();
        syncPoints(is.isDragAllPaths || is.isDragLastPath ? true : false);
        console.log('textHandler onReturnKeyPressed');
    }
```

EDIT: Looks like this is only happening when using Chrome. Firefox doesn't care whether the app is local or web based enter key always works.

EDIT 2: So I added console.log to the event handler. Locally all keypress up and down events are logged locally. When deployed to my AWS lightsail instance they no longer fire in Chrome or Edge (chromium). They do work in Firefox and Brave however.

Here are the keyup and keydown handlers:

```
var keyCode;

function onkeydown(e) {
    console.log('KeyDown: ', e);

    keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;

    if (keyCode == 8 || keyCode == 46) {
        if (isBackKey(e, keyCode)) {
        }
        return;
    }

    if (keyCode == 13 && is.isText) {
        textHandler.onReturnKeyPressed();
        return;
    }

    if (e.metaKey) {
        isControlKeyPressed = true;
        keyCode = 17;
    }

    if (!isControlKeyPressed && keyCode === 17) {
        isControlKeyPressed = true;
    }
}

function onkeyup(e) {
    console.log('KeyUp: ', e);

    if (e.which == null && (e.charCode != null || e.keyCode != null)) {
        e.which = e.charCode != null ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    }

    keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which || 0;
  
    if (keyCode == 8 || keyCode == 46) {
        if (isBackKey(e, keyCode)) {
            textHandler.writeText(textHandler.lastKeyPress, true);
        }
        return;
    }

    // Ctrl + t
    if (isControlKeyPressed && keyCode === 84 && is.isText) {
        textHandler.showTextTools();
        return;
    }

    // Ctrl + z
    if (isControlKeyPressed && keyCode === 90) {
        if (points.length) {
            points.length = points.length - 1;
            drawHelper.redraw();

            syncPoints(is.isDragAllPaths || is.isDragLastPath ? true : false);
        }
    }

    // Ending the Control Key
    if (typeof e.metaKey !== 'undefined' && e.metaKey === false) {
        isControlKeyPressed = false;
        keyCode = 17;
    }

    if (keyCode === 17) {
        isControlKeyPressed = false;
    }
}
```

See below console logged events fine locally:
[image: chrome console]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are you cached with old code?

Comment: I would out a debugger in chrome inspect and see if it reaches to the event handler callback.

Comment: Keep in mind inputs inside a form natively submit the enclosing form when enter is pressed. Its best practice to move logic into the submit event handler instead of attaching to an event directly on the input.

Comment: @epascarello no I cleared the cache with crtl+f5

Comment: I wonder does it have something to do with the isTrusted flag?